I cant find AVD Manager on Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
I upgrade the Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
And I can't find AVD Manager. Why?
So I can't test my application.


Goto: Tools - device manager. On the right toolbar, third icon from the top

I pushed "Dart Enable".
